# Determining the SubMenu of a MenuItem

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, android-menu

I have a `NavigationView` in my app. Inside the menu for the `NavView`, I have two sub menus:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_group_one"
        android:title="SubMenu A">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:checkable="true"
                android:title="One"/>
            <item
                android:checkable="true"
                android:title="Two"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_group_two"
        android:title="SubMenu B">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:checkable="true"
                android:title="Three"/>
            <item
                android:checkable="true"
                android:title="Four"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

In my activity's `onNavigationItemSelected()` I would like to be able to figure out which sub menu the selected item is in. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I haven't found an existing solution at this time, however I have found a workaround:

To solve this with minimal additional XML overhead, wrap each set of sub-menu items in a group, with an Id:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_group_one"
        android:title="SubMenu A">
        <menu>
            <group id="@+id/nav_group_wrapper_one">
                <item
                    android:checkable="true"
                    android:title="One"/>
                <item
                    android:checkable="true"
                    android:title="Two"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_group_two"
        android:title="SubMenu B">
        <menu>
            <group id="@+id/nav_group_wrapper_two">
                <item
                    android:checkable="true"
                    android:title="Three"/>
                <item
                    android:checkable="true"
                    android:title="Four"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

This way, one can simply call `item.getGroupId()` to infer the sub-menu it is contained within.